# Cropper js React fixed crop size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cropperjs

I'm using [react-cropper](https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper) and need fixed crop size. Try to do it as follows:

```
<Cropper
            ref='cropper'
            src='babyanimal_open.jpg'
            style={{height: 400, width: '100%'}}
            // Cropper.js options
            ready={this._ready.bind(this)}
            cropBoxResizable={false}

            cropBoxData={{ width: 100, height: 50 }}
            guides={false}
            crop={this._crop.bind(this)} />
```

Result is an empty screen w/o any errors.

Comment: Did you include cropper.css as mentioned in the docs?

Comment: No, but I do not use pure cropper.js, but npm packaged react-cropper, what is a React wrapper around cropper.js. I believe css is included by default in react-cropper,  am I wrong?

Comment: Docs say that CSS should be added manually.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this package, it has no dependencies and both work for web and mobile client.

react-avatar-image-cropper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-avatar-image-cropper

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct ref, like mine code down below.

```
ref={cropper=>this.cropper = cropper}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer to  this question is ref is not a string , use

```html
 let cropperRef=React.useRef();
 
 ref={cropperRef}
```